# php way to leave website frame and return

Tags: php, security, iframe

I have an app which is being required to run inside the frame of a website. The issue is I have to authenticate with a third party to get data for the website. The third party requires the app to not be in a frame when authenticating. So my app must leave the website frame, authenticate with the third party to get it's data, and then return the data inside the frame and process the data.

Is there a way to do this in PHP ?

Comment: Have you tried doing the authentication in a popup?

Comment: Frame as in [Frame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp)? That frame that doesn't exist anymore in the modern web?

Comment: @GolezTrol Likely an iframe.

Comment: How about using a query string? When you have authenticated, just change the URL of the frame (I suppose you mean iframe) to something representing the data you need.

Comment: I assume it's an iframe on their site yes. I'm actually turning over control to the third party app so the user can log in there and approve the data transfer.  Then I can reach back and grab the data, finally I can return to the iframe. Don't think a query string or popup would do all this.